# How to apply as.Date function in multi column without knowing the index R

Tags: r, lapply, as.date

**Desire to convert class of multi cols without knowing the location .**

This is the dataset

```
# Dataset name call : df . # It is a example , real data has many columns
# that you cannot have a clear index by one sight.

A.Date      Price  B.Date       C.Date      Size    D.Date
2017-01-01   502   2017-01-03   2017-11-01   45.4   2016-10-01
2015-01-31   602   2017-02-03   2013-07-11   65.4   2016-03-24
```

I have a code like below :

```
 df[,grepl("Date",colnames(df))] <-
 lapply(df[,grepl("Date",colnames(df))],function(x) as.Date(x))
```

But its turn out error :

```
Error in strptime(x, f) : input string is too long
```

Even i tried this code :

```
 DateCol <- grep("Date",names(df)) 
 df[,c(DateCol)] <- as.Date(df[,c(DateCol)])
```

It goes by error again like 
Error in as.Date.default(df[, c(DateCol)]) : 
   'df[, c(DateCol)]' class “Date” cannot be defined

What is wrong with the code and what is the solution ?

Comment: Can you show the `class` of the columns.   The second solution will not work because `as.Date` needs a `vector` or column as input.  I have doubts about the `class` of the 'Date' columns

Comment: All Date columns class are " Character" . thankyou neilfws

Comment: sorry that i forget to mention one important point that , some of the Date cols cannot be converted. Because its contain  : "2017-01-01 ; 2018-01-01 " in one element . So the solution should avoid these type of col but convert the normal type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although, @Tung has been provided a good solution still I feel `dplyr::mutate_at` should be more appropriate choice in this case since columns expected to be changed to `Date`
contains `Date` as part of their names. Hence if dataframe contains other `character` types columns then `mutate_at` will provide flexibiltiy to choose columns.

`grep("Date",names(.), value = TRUE)` provides list of columns wihch contains `Date` as part of their name.

`mutate_at` applies `as.Date` function to convert those columns to `Date` type.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(grep("Date",names(.), value = TRUE)), funs(as.Date))

#      A.Date Price     B.Date    C.Date Size     D.Date
#1 2017-01-01   502 2017-01-03 2017-11-01 45.4 2016-10-01
#2 2015-01-31   602 2017-02-03 2013-07-11 65.4 2016-03-24
```

Comment: Thankyou MKR , This is an good example for apply grep in mutate_at. They are work in one operation.

Answer (score 1):

If your xxx.Date columns are character then

```r
library(dplyr)

txt <- "A.Date      Price  B.Date       C.Date      Size    D.Date
2017-01-01   502   2017-01-03   2017-11-01   45.4   2016-10-01
2015-01-31   602   2017-02-03   2013-07-11   65.4   2016-03-24"

dat <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)

res <- dat %>% 
  mutate_if(is.character, as.Date)
str(res)  

> str(res)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ A.Date: Date, format: "2017-01-01" ...
 $ Price : int  502 602
 $ B.Date: Date, format: "2017-01-03" ...
 $ C.Date: Date, format: "2017-11-01" ...
 $ Size  : num  45.4 65.4
 $ D.Date: Date, format: "2016-10-01" ...
```

Created on 2018-03-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thankyou Tung. But what arguments  should fill after "is.character" and "as.Date" ? *Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: character string is not in a standard unambiguous format.

Comment: You don't need any argument. `mutate_if` checks if the columns are characters then converts them to `Date`. Try restart your R session (Ctrl + Shift + F10 in RStudio), then run my code only

Comment: Thank you Tung , your approach work . THe Error occur it was because some of the Date column contain double date like : "2019-01-31;2017-02-02", making all the answer the viewer not work. My problem that couldn't raise question properly to solve my situation that need apply to all columns contain "Date" and also drop multi date columns .